# Prevent child object being queried in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two POJO classes Quote and RQuote, where RQuote is defined as a child of Quote. In the two corresponding hbm.xml files, no relation is defined between the two classes.

The problem is, I have a hql as " select sum(q.packagePrice) from Quote q ". This hql will query both the Quote and RQuote object thus it returns two sum values.

I want the sum function to be run on Quote object only, not on its child RQuote. Is there anyway to do this in Hibernate? Thanks for your help.

Quote

```
public class Quote extends Base implements Auditable {
    protected Client user;
    protected Package subscriptionPackage;

    // Default noarg constructor
    public Quote() {}

    // Accessors

    public Client getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Client user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Package getSubscriptionPackage() {
        return subscriptionPackage;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionPackage(Package subscriptionPackage) {
        this.subscriptionPackage = subscriptionPackage;
    }


    public String getType() {
        return "Quote";
    }

}

public class RQuote extends Quote  {

    // Default noarg constructor
    public RQuote() {}

    public String getType() {
        return "RQuote";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide an outline of your classes?

Comment: I added the Quote example and RQuote. There is no association/collection declared in Quote or RQuote. Any suggestion about the problem. Thanks

Comment: Can't see anything immediately useful as to why it would do that - I asume that both classes are in different tables as per '9.1.6. Table per concrete class using implicit polymorphism' on hibernate.org?

Answer (score 0):

This is your mistake:

```
RQuote extends Quote
```

You define RQuote as a subclass of Quote. In consequence every instance of RQuote *also* is an instance of Quote.

Now when Hibernate is evaluating `select sum(q.packagePrice) from Quote q` it first looks in its cache for all instances of Quote which are already loaded, and there it also finds the instances of RQuote, which are instances of Quote, too, and uses them. As a result, all RQuote which were loaded before by any other query in the same session will be included in your sum.

Also Query.list() or Query.uniqueResult will not work as expected.

So you have to correct your Java class RQuote and do not let it extend Quote.

Comment: Thank you for all the comment. In this case, RQuote is defined for some other purpose and it has to be a child of Quote. I am trying to fix the side effect caused by adding of this class. That's why I have to keep the subclass but prevent the child object to be loaded for that specif hql. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Session.createQuery does not work correctly if one entity class is a subclass of another entity class. Forget fixing the side effects - which side effects appear depends of the order of selects - so you never will be sure your application is working.

Comment: There might be two solutions if RQuote really must extend Quote: 1) Use StatelessSession instead of Session. StatelessSession does not cache elements, so the problem might not appear. Bear in mind StatelessSession has many disadvantages. 2) You create an abstract class AbstractQuote, which contains all the methods and elements which are common for Quote and RQuote, and which does not have a hibernate mapping. Then you create `Quote extends AbstractQuote` and `RQuote extends AbstractQuote` (but no direct relationship between Quote and RQuote). - Both propositions I didn't try yet, no guarantee.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried with StatelessSession. StatelessSession.createQuery method returns the same result as a stateful session does. I will try the abstract class then